# create hyperlink in visual basic excel between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

When I used this formula,

```
Sub IndexingSheets()
    Sheets(1).Range("B3").Formula = _
    "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name & "!A5"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
    Sheets(2).Range("A5").Formula = _
    "=HYPERLINK(""#" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "!B3"", ""TextToDisplay"")"
End Sub
```

it creates a hyperlink but when I click it, it shows reference is not valid. Then when I changed the formula in the formula bar, I added the filename and it worked so it will now look like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xls]'Sheet2 123!A5", "gg")
```

But originally it is just like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2 123!G20", "gg")
```

How can I alter my original code which I shown on the topmost so that this:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xls]'Sheet2 123!A5", "gg")
```

will be shown or will be the format in the formula bar? my problem is how can i put the filename now without just copying the filename itself and not just pasting it in the code?

I just want to clarify that there's a messagebox that says you should input the 2nd name of the sheet. so the  name of the sheet is not just "Sheet2" anymore.

For instance you put in the msgbox "123", the name of the sheet would now become "Sheet2 123". the messagebox is already present, no need to create a code for it.

Comment: but it says compile error?

Comment: ok let me test it out.

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to put single-quotes around the sheet names, to account for the possible spaces in sheet names.  If you omit single-quotes, then the sheet names *must* not contain any spaces.

```
Sub IndexingSheets()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets(1).Range("B3").Formula = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & .Sheets(2).Name & "'!A5"", ""Jump to Sheet2!A5"")"
        .Sheets(2).Range("A5").Formula = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & .Sheets(1).Name & "'!B3"", ""Jump to Sheet1!B3"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

To include the Workbook name (not necessary, I don't think):

```
Sub IndexingSheets()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets(1).Range("B3").Formula = _
            "=HYPERLINK(""#'[" & .Name & "]" & .Sheets(2).Name & "'!A5"", _
            ""Jump to Sheet2!A5"")"
        .Sheets(2).Range("A5").Formula = _
            "=HYPERLINK(""#'[" & .Name & "]" & .Sheets(1).Name & "'!B3"", _
            ""Jump to Sheet1!B3"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

And, an alternate method of achieving the same -- this one includes the Workbook name, too:

```
Sub IndexingSheetsWithFileName()
    With ThisWorkbook

        .Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Sheets(1).Range("B3"), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'[" & .Name & "]" & .Sheets(2).Name & "'!A5", _
            TextToDisplay:="Jump to Sheet2!A5"

        .Sheets(2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Sheets(2).Range("A5"), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'[" & .Name & "]" & .Sheets(1).Name & "'!B3", _
            TextToDisplay:="Jump to Sheet1!B3"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: no need as long as it works. finally it worked! thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem! I added it in, anyways.

Comment: i have a question, what if i don't want the code/formula to show in the formula bar? the text for instance "Jump to Sheet" will just show. what code can i used?

Comment: I would suggest using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, with the `Application.GoTo` method. If you have trouble with that, or can't figure it out, post a new question like "How to make a normal cell behave like a hyperlink".